# jquery attr and eq

Tags: jquery

I have a menu, I want to add class "current" to the `<li>` with `id="home"`, so this is what I tried:

```
$('#main-nav ul li').attr('id').eq('home').addClass('current');
```

I also tried .is instead of .eq, non of them works!

How I could achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#main-nav ul li#home').addClass('current');
```

You can easily select for specific ids with the CSS id selector #.
Depending on your DOM, you can even be more specific with your selectors, which will result in faster selection of the dom element:

```
$('#main-nav > ul > li#home').addClass('current');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using id, so you can use id selector, no need to use `attr` or `eq`:

```
$('#home').addClass('current');
```

Comment: I "think" he wants to do it in the same statement there, other than that, you're right of course.

Comment: Hard to say, seems to me that behz4d just wants to add class there.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the `id of li` which is `home` in your case in the same way you used this `id main` at the beginning of selector.

Try this,

```
$('#main-nav ul li#home').addClass('current');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an ID on the li element, you can just do this:

```
$('#home').addClass('current');
```